# How to make loops more efficient?

Tags: java

I am having a problem with a basic code which displays some animated images in a 150x150 grid on the screen. (Note: Yes i know the images go off the edge of the screen but in the end i was planning to scale the images as required to fit the screen). However the program only runs at 2 FPS causing the animation to sometimes not work. My loop is currently as follows (in Java):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        g2d.drawImage(getImage(texture_Ocean,l),i*64,j*64,i*64+64,j*64+64,0,0,64,64,this);
    }
}
```

And getImage:

```
public Image getImage(Image i, Long l) {
    BufferedImage b = (BufferedImage) i;
    int w = b.getWidth();
    if (b.getHeight() % w == 0) {
        int frames = b.getHeight()/w;
        int frame = Math.round((l%1000)/(1000/frames));
        System.out.println(frame);
        return b.getSubimage(0,(int) (w*frame) ,w, w);
    } else {
        return texture_error;
    }
}
```

My question is how can i make my program more efficient/run quicker? I know there has to be a way to do it as you see games such as prison architect and rimworld with words that are 300x300 and have hundreads of entities. And games such as TF2 which display thousands of polygons in 3D space. How?

Comment: I'm not a computer graphics guru by a long shot, but I'm fairly sure the faster frame rate of the games you list is because they use a library like OpenGL that interfaces directly with the relevant facilities of the GPU.

Comment: I'm not positive what texture_Ocean is, but if you can save off in a static or member variable, and get the width and height, you save some  good processing each iteration right there.

Comment: It might not improve much but you could cache getImage as it always return the same thing, now does the inner calculation by each cycle

Comment: You should do some profiling first to (a) make sure, this piece of code is your performance bottleneck and (b) find out about what exactly causes it. Everything else is just guessing.

Comment: @GREnvoy texture_Ocean is a variable of type Image which is initialized in the Applet init() event.

Comment: @HamoriZ getImage returns different each cycle, the variable l passed to it is a tick counter, causing the animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the CPU (and through inefficient memory access methods as well) to do a job that the GPU is much better for.

You need to look at using something like a 2d graphics or games library or similar to get the sort of performance you are looking for.

Comment: See this question for some suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883018/is-using-swingutilities-invokelater-inside-a-java-game-loop-a-bad-practice/24883129?noredirect=1#comment38670638_24883129

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, when developing games, you should care a lot with optimization. You can't simply call a paint method if you don't need it, and hope everything will be alright.

Besides that, you should try to look for a library dedicated to graphics (like OpenGL), since they can handle the optimization easily with the hardware.